# number of equation in number field

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Suppose I have a number field $K$ of degree $n$ with $n = r_1 + 2 r_2$,
where $r_1$ is the number of real embeddings and $r_2$ is the
number of complex conjugate pairs.

Suppose $v$ is a totally positive algebraic integer in $K$.
Consider an equation
$$
v = \mu_1^k + .. + \mu_s^k
$$
for some natural numbers $s$ and $k$,
where each $\mu_i$ is a totally positive algebraic integer in $K$.
If $r_2>0$, then the number of solution is not necessary finite
[Generalization of Waring's Problem to Algebraic number 
fields by Carl L. Siegel].
I was wondering if someone could give me a specific example
where the number of solution is infinite
when $r_1>0$ and $r_2 > 0$
or
how to show it is finite when $r_2 = 0$
.
Thanks!